# pytest fails on Azure Devops under python 3.7 but passes under 3.8

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, pytest

I am currently running a suite of 37 `pytest` tests on a python application.  I am building under `python 3.7.2` and locally all tests passes.  On Azure DevOps pipleline I also test for `python 3.8`.  Here is the `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python37:
      python.version: '3.7'
    Python38:
      python.version: '3.8'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'


- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

Under the `3.7` run I have a specific test that fails on `assert` with an actual calculated value:

```
self = <unit_tests.test_services_string_jb_router.TestServicesRectilinearRouter object at 0x7f5404e88fd0>
def test_create_block_when_called_calculates_correct_total_string_cable_length(self):
designer = BlockDesigner(CsvStore(self.config), self.router, self.config)
block = designer.create_block("BK1")
result = block.total_cable_length
>       assert result == 4943.176
E       assert 4932.926 == 4943.176
unit_tests/test_services_string_jb_router.py:28: AssertionError
```

The test however passes under the `3.8` run.

The fact that the code produces an actual value, just a wrong one, would suggest it gets an incorrect configuration *but only under `python 3.7` and not `python 3.8`!*.

I run a `setup_method` at the start of test classes with a `str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())` prefix to ensure cross platform compatibility.

Where do I even start looking for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

...and there it passes without my doing anything about it.  Assume it was some older config sitting in and uncleared cache somewhere in Azure.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly sharing. You could *mark your reply as an answer*, which will also help others in the community.

Comment: Alas, I am running into similar problems again.  I have tests failing in DevOps with different test value outputs to those locally.  Also under python 3.7 I have 9 failing tests and under the python 3.8 pipeline I have 5 different failing tests.  The tests seem to be running with outdated input data yet all files it requires are similar to the ones I have locally.  Even tried to push some of these files again to no avail.

Comment: So now all tests passes under 3.7 but 1 fails under python 3.8.  This inconsistency is frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly update Paul. Sounds a little wired. What's the result if you run the same tests in your local environment with python3.8? You have mentioned  building under python 3.7.2 and locally all tests passes.

Comment: I have unfortunately not found a resolution to this issue.  It passes under 3.8 locally.  i have resorted to mark the test to xfail under Python 3.8.

Comment: Hi @Paul Thanks for your update. Besides you could also deploy a self-host Linux/Windows agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) instead of using Microsoft host agent. And try to make sure you have the same environment as your local develop machine. This may do the trick. Or help you narrow down the issue.